# Razer tiamat 2.2 microphone

Tags: skype, microphone

I have a problem with my Razer Tiamat 2.2. I don't know if it's the headset itself or the microphone, but whenever I'm on skype, my friends can hear everything that I can hear. Almost as clearly as I can.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause can be, that you dont use your headset-microphone. Have you an integrated microphone in your PC/Notebook? Skype uses the built-in-microphone if you don't change it yourself.

Comment: I'm sure that I used my headset-microphone, since I tried tapping the microphone and could clearly hear the sound.

Comment: @Kresten Take a look at the audio-settings. Does they hear everything, even if you dont talk? Eventually, the sensitivity of your microphone is to high.

Comment: Nope, nothing. I tested the sensitivity by saying nothing, actually even trying very low sounds, and I couldn't hear that at all, so it's not the sensitivity

Comment: @Kresten But your friend heard that, when you tested it, like you said?

Comment: Well, I used the echo sound test service on skype, but no there wasn't anything